# Set theory - Logic proof verification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Prove that:
$$
\mathscr P(U_{i\in I}A_i)\subset U_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i) \rightarrow \exists i \in I\ \forall j \in I (A_j \subset A_i)
$$

---

Here are the definitions I've used to figure out how to prove it:
$$
U{i\in I} A_i = \{ k \text{ | }\exists i \in I(k\in A_i) \}\\
U{i\in I} \mathscr P(A_i) = \{ k \text{ | }\exists i \in I(k\in \mathscr P(A_i)) \} = \{ k \text{ | }\exists i \in I(k \subset A_i) \}
$$

---

Here's my proof.

It's true that $\forall j \in I: A_j \subset U_{i\in I}A_i$, thus $A_j \in \mathscr P(U_{i\in I}A_i)$. Therefore $\forall j \in I:A_j \in U_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i)$ which is the same as $ \forall j \in I: \big( \exists i \in I (A_j \subset A_i) \big)$.

But I want to prove that: 
$$
\exists i \in I: \big( \forall j \in I (A_j \subset  A_i) \big)
$$

So now I'll prove : $\forall j \in I: \big( \exists i \in I (A_j \subset  A_i) \big) \rightarrow \exists i \in I: \big( \forall j \in I (A_j \subset  A_i) \big)$ by contradiction.

Let $i$ be an arbitrary element of $I$. Therefore $A_{j0} \not\subset  A_i$. That contradicts the fact that $ \forall j \in I: \big( \exists i \in I (A_j \subset  A_i) \big) $, hence $\exists i \in I: \big( \forall j \in I (A_j \subset  A_i) \big)$.

---

I'm new to math formalism and I struggled to get this. Is everything correct? I know that I'm using a lot of logic symbols, but it's because it's still more clear to me to write a proof like that then write it using plain English. I'm open to constructive criticism, and hope for a help.

Thanks!

Comment: What you've proved is true regardless of any hypothesis (take $i=j$). You need to use something else (your proof by contradiction doesn't make much sense)

Comment: @Max I agree with you, but the first proof makes sense and is correct for you? The second one I'm still trying to figure it out, but it's making sense for me at the moment!

Comment: What do you call "first proof" ?

Comment: @Max , sorry, it's all the same proof. I was talking about the first part, when I concluded: $\forall j \in I: \big( \exists i \in I (A_j \subset A_i) \big)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not commentary on your proof, see David C. Ullrich's earlier answer for that.  Here is an alternative proof that might appeal to you, because of your preference for using symbols-- so we will try to use them to our advantage here.$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \{\:}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\{\:} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \:\} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\equiv}{\leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\P}[1]{\mathscr P\left(#1\right)}
%$

Letting $\;i,j\;$ range over your index set $\;I\;$, you are asked to prove
$$
\tag{0}
\P{\cup_j A_j} \subset \cup_i \P{A_i}
\;\then\;
\exists i \forall j (A_j \subset A_i)
$$
(I've renamed your leftmost $\;\cup_i\;$ to $\;\cup_j\;$, to avoid having to rename in the middle of the proof below.)

So let's start with what seems to be the most complex side of $\Ref{0}$, the left hand side, expand the definitions and simplify, and work towards the other side.

---

We calculate as follows:

$$\calc
    \P{\cup_j A_j} \;\subset\; \cup_i \P{A_i}
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\subset\;$}
    \forall D \left(D \in \P{\cup_j A_j} \;\then\; D \in \cup_i \P{A_i}\right)
\op\equiv\hint{LHS: definition of $\;\P{\ldots}\;$; RHS: definition of $\;\cup_\ldots\;$}
    \forall D \left(D \subset \cup_j A_j \;\then\; \exists i (D \in \P{A_i})\right)
\op{\then \tag{*}}\hints{choose $\;D := \cup_j A_j\;$, using $\;\forall V(V \subset V)\;$}\hints{-- the simplest way I see to move $\;\exists\;$ to the outside,}\hint{which is what the RHS of $\Ref{0}$ requires}
    \exists i (\cup_j A_j \in \P{A_i})
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\P{\ldots}\;$}
    \exists i (\cup_j A_j \subset A_i)
\op\equiv\hint{basic property of $\;\cup_\ldots\;$}
    \exists i \forall j (A_j \subset A_i)
\endcalc$$

---

Note how this proof consists almost completely of applying definitions and basic properties, driven by our desire to reach the RHS of $\Ref{0}$.

The only step that required some "inspiration" is the key step $\Ref{*}$.  But even there, the symbols --the shape of the formulas-- help to motivate this step.  And so the key choice, which is to consider the set $\;\cup_j A_j\;$, is not a complete surprise anymore, as in the earlier answer.  Instead it has become something that seems at least reasonable to try.

Finally, note how leaving out $\;\in I\;$ throughout makes the formulas much easier to read.

$%
\endgroup
%$

Answer (score 0):

You can't prove $\forall j \in I: \big( \exists i \in I (A_j \subset  A_i) \big) \rightarrow \exists i \in I: \big( \forall j \in I (A_j \subset  A_i) \big)$, by contradiction or otherwise, because it's not true. (Your proof of this makes no sense. First, you have no reason for saying that $A_{j_0}\not\subset A_i$, and more important if you did know this was true it would *not* contradict the fact that $\forall_{j\in I}\exists_{i\in I}A_j\subset A_i$, because of the "$\exists_{i\in I}$".)

**Hint** for proving the implication at the top: Let $$A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i.$$

$\newcommand\P{\mathcal P}$

Then $A\in\P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)$, so the hypothesis implies that $$A\in\bigcup_{i\in I}\P(A_i).$$So (by definition of union) there exists $j\in I$ such that $A\in \P(A_j)$.

**Edit:** I've been asked to explain my thought processes in defining $A$ the way I did. I don't recall what I was actually thinking at the time, but it seems fairly natural:

The hypothesis says exactly that if $A\subset\bigcup_1 A_i$ then there exists $j$ such that $A\subset A_j$. Hmm, what choice of $A$ would allow us to conclude $A_i\subset A_j$ for every $j$, given $A\subset A_j$? Oh of course, that would follow if $A_i\subset A$ for every $i$... Is there an $A\subset \bigcup_iA_i$ such that $A_i\subset A$ for every $i$?

Comment: About your hint: could you try and convey your thought process around why to try this specific A? I only found this (see my answer) by formally expanding all involved definitions. I'm really curious how you arrived at it? As you presented it, it felt a bit magical. :-)

Comment: @MarnixKlooster See edit. Regarding your comment about how you only found it by formally expanding all the definitions: Well of course - I used the definitions as well! Something this "low-level" one can't expect to apply fancy theorems, if it's true it "must" be immediate from the definitions.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! So you basically did the same thing I did, except that for me, it was much easier to discover this by starting to write down the calculation until I reached $\;\forall D \left(D\subset\cup_j A_j\;\rightarrow\;\exists i (D\in\P{A_i})\right)\;$, and discover how to move the $\;\exists\;$ to the outer/top level. So for me, it is much easier to let the symbols do the work.  And (at least to me) it seems better to have a proof with the least amount of "magic" for the reader, instead of just starting it with something like "Let $\;A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\;$." Thanks again!

Comment: Whatever. Regarding "magic": We seem to agree that working through the definitions is sufficient to explain why one would define $A$ the way I did. I don't know who you are, but for future reference: If you are or become a mathematican and you comment that you "had to" work through the definitions to follow something, implying that the presentation was hence somehow incomplete, people will look at you funny. If _merely_ working through the definitions is sufficient then the argument _is_ complete! An author writing for grownups is entitled to  use trivial consequences of the definitons...